# 02 Accord, rough idle and hesitates when cold

Tags: honda, accord, cold-start

2002 Honda Accord EX,  L4-2254cc 2.3L SOHC (VTEC) MFI, 108,000 miles. Recently bought it from a private owner and was told nothing was wrong with the car.

Car starts rough when the engine is cold. Sounds like its choking. Giving it gas does the same, it chokes a few times and revs. It also hesitates when driving but only when the engine is cold. Once the engine gets hot enough it drives like there's not a single thing wrong. Drove it out on the freeway once, car was fine until I got up to 70 mph, then car started to hesitate again. RPM wouldn't go past 3500 and the check engine light started flashing. I managed to get out of the freeway and took the local road. The car drove like it had no problem. The next day I started the car, the check engine light was gone. I managed to get it checked before it went away and code was P1399.

All I've done so far is to replace all 4 spark plugs (NGK) and distributor cap and rotor.

This hasn't solved the problem. I don't know much about cars so if anyone knows about anything I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Do you have any kind of scanner that will read live data?

Comment: i know a person that does. he checked voltage ratings on some things and he said everything seems to be normal. we cant get any codes of the car since the engine light had turned off but u can still feel the miss fire from the way the engine is running. im thinking of changing the O2 sensor.

Comment: i live in illinois and the weather is starting to get warm so starting the car is not much of a problem anymore, im just hoping to get it fix before winter comes around again.

Comment: I faced same problem , like yours I tried to clean the throttle body , but the problem doesn't go!

Answer (score 2):

Honda assigns the P1399 code for random misfires.  On some models this is caused by a clogged EGR Port. The Valve clearance may also be an issue.

Another possible cause is the intake air temperature sensor. If it's reading incorrectly it can cause the cold start problem you are having, an possibly even the high speed problem as well.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will check the EGR port first thing tomorrow and if it doesn't work then check the intake air temp sensor.

Comment: @bruce If you found my answer useful click the upvote button. It's the up arrow above the number to the left of the post.

Comment: Larry, bruce doesn't currently have the "vote up" privilege.

Comment: @JoshCaswell New users can comment and vote on there own questions immediately

Comment: Comment yes, [vote no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1661/159251). The [vote up privilege](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) requires 15 rep on all but private beta sites.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nice, it's been so long since I was new I forgot.